# Is it possible to read CPU voltage on an Android device without root?

Tags: java, android, cpu, proc

I'm trying to write an app that reads, but cannot change CPU voltage.  Do I need root permissions?  In either case (yes or no), could you please run me through how this might be done?

Thank you very much!